# Perform Validation in 3 tier architecture

Tags: c#, winforms

in which layer do we perfrom validation 
if i perform in bll layer i cannot use function like messagebox 
this program is working correctly i juss need to perfrom validtion can u guys help me out just to perform validation for fname if it is null or not
in bll class

```
public void InsertEmployee(string fname, string lname, string alias, 
                           string contact, string address, string company,
                           string bdate, string email)
{

    try 
    {
        obj.InsertEmployee(fname,lname,alias,contact,address,company,bdate,email);
    }       
    catch (Exception ex)  
    {  
        throw ex;  
    }  
}
```

in Dal class

```
public void InsertEmployee(string fname, string lname, string alias,
                           string contact, string address, string company, 
                           string bdate, string email)
{
    string query;
    try  
    {
        query = "insert into cntc_employee values('" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + alias + "','" + contact + "','" + address + "','" + company + "','" + bdate + "','" + email + "')";
        OpenCnn();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally 
    {
        CloseCnn();
    }
}
```

in my ui class

```
private void cmdins_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fname = txtfname.Text;
    string lname = txtlname.Text;
    string alias = txtalias.Text;
    string contact = txtcon.Text;
    string address = txtadd.Text;
    string company = txtcomp.Text;
    string date = datetimepicker.Value.ToShortDateString();
    string email = txtemail.Text;
    try
    {
        obj.InsertEmployee(fname,lname,alias,contact,address,company,date,email);
        MessageBox.Show(txtfname.Text.Trim() + " employee is successfully added.");
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. And use _using statement_ to dispose your database connections.

Answer (score 0):

In short, **everywhere**. Of course, there is a longer answer that begins with "it depends..." but lets focus on a clear and concise SHORT/EASY answer. Your client can perform validation but does your business logic layer trust that client? What about other clients? The database in itself will have constraints, lengths of strings etc.

So, basically you need to put it everywhere that makes sense. Yes, there will be some duplication but better that than some rubbish data making its way through into the database and breaking something else further down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Validation is IMHO a business concern, so that's is where it belongs.

The method of returning the validation-result is different issue. So no, your business-layer should not do a `MessageBox.Show`, that should only be done in your UI layer. But you can for instance return the validation-result in a string to the UI layer where you called the business-layer, and there you can show a messagebox. Another options is to throw a validation-exception, and catch this in your UI layer.

Yes, you can perform validation elsewhere too where it is logical to do so. For instance, you can perform client-side validation of your views when the user clicks a save button, that way the response will be quicker, and more user-friendly.

### Update

To add validation in the business layer, one option is to do it like this.

Note: this is a fairly simple straightforward way to do this.

Note: I've removed you try-catch where you did `throw ex` in the catch. You loose the stacktrace this way, and since you didn't actually handle the exception, it can be completely removed.

```
// Add reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations if necessary
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public void InsertEmployee(string fname, string lname, string alias, 
                           string contact, string address, string company,
                           string bdate, string email) {
    ValidateEmployee(fname,lname,alias,contact,address,company,bdate,email);
    obj.InsertEmployee(fname,lname,alias,contact,address,company,bdate,email);
}

private void ValidateEmployee(string fname, string lname, string alias, 
                              string contact, string address, string company,
                              string bdate, string email) {
    var validationErrors = new List<string>();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fname))
        validationErrors.Add("First name is a required field.");
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lname))
        validationErrors.Add("Last name is a required field.");
    // Etc... add other validations

    if (validationErrors.Any()) {
        throw new ValidationException(string.Join(" ", validationErrors));
    }
}
```

Please note that your initial setup can be improved substantially. Things like:

- Create classes to represent domain objects (aka *entities*). From your example: add a class Employee which has properties like FName, LName, Alias, etc
- Use these classes wherever you now write all the variables. Much simplere.
- Use databinding in your form to eliminate all the txtsomething.Text = fname, and vice versa.
- Use parameterized queries. Or better, use a component to save your entities to the database, ***an ORM***. An example is **Entity Framework**.

Comment: can u help me write a few lines of code m new to 3 tier

Comment: thnx how to throw exception in ui then

Comment: You don't have to throw it, it is already thrown when you catch it in the business-layer. So if you don't catch it there, it will be caught in the UI layer.

Comment: it says The type or namespace name 'ValidationException' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Have you added the reference I mentioned? System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.

Comment: oh its ok but it is still inserting   empty field